# Unhandled exception at 0x0F28EA8E (msvcr110d.dll) in Final Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x9F5A339A

Tags: c++, function

Alright, so while I know I am missing something super easy, I have no idea what it is. I have looked through every related question looking for an answer to mine, and all that I can determine is that Im somewhere going out of scope I think. I have no pointers or anything.

My problem came up today, as I am trying to make a function that draws player0 and 1's first hands. This program is going to be a very dumb'd down version of MTG.

Here is my code,I hope I format this properly.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void InitDeck (string Deck [40] [4])    // Makes the first player's deck
    //Column 0 is Name, 1 is Mana Cost, 2 is strengthm 3 is toughness.
{
    //Is there any way to make this a short and not a string
    Deck [0] [0] = "AEther Adept";              Deck [0] [1] = "3";         Deck [0] [2] = "3";     Deck [0] [3] = "2";
    Deck [1] [0] = "Alabaster Mage";            Deck [1] [1] = "2";         Deck [0] [2] = "2";     Deck [0] [3] = "1";
    Deck [2] [0] = "Arablest Elite";            Deck [2] [1] = "4";         Deck [0] [2] = "2";     Deck [0] [3] = "3";
    Deck [3] [0] = "Ardent Recruit";            Deck [3] [1] = "1";         Deck [0] [2] = "1";     Deck [0] [3] = "1";
    Deck [4] [0] = "Auramancer";                Deck [4] [1] = "3";         Deck [0] [2] = "2";     Deck [0] [3] = "2";
    Deck [5] [0] = "Auriok Edgewright";         Deck [5] [1] = "2";         Deck [0] [2] = "2";     Deck [0] [3] = "2";
    Deck [6] [0] = "Auriok Senchaser";          Deck [6] [1] = "2";         Deck [0] [2] = "1";     Deck [0] [3] = "1";
    Deck [7] [0] = "Auriok Survivors";          Deck [7] [1] = "6";         Deck [0] [2] = "4";     Deck [0] [3] = "6";
    Deck [8] [0] = "Azure Mage";                Deck [8] [1] = "3";         Deck [0] [2] = "2";     Deck [0] [3] = "1";
    Deck [9] [0] = "Benalish Veteran";          Deck [9] [1] = "3";         Deck [0] [2] = "2";     Deck [0] [3] = "2";
    Deck [10] [0] = "Blade Splicer";            Deck [10] [1] = "3";        Deck [0] [2] = "1";     Deck [0] [3] = "1";
    Deck [11] [0] = "Blade-Tribe Bersekers";    Deck [11] [1] = "4";        Deck [0] [2] = "3";     Deck [0] [3] = "3";
    Deck [12] [0] = "Blighted Agent";           Deck [12] [1] = "2";        Deck [0] [2] = "1";     Deck [0] [3] = "1";
    Deck [13] [0] = "Blind Zealot";             Deck [13] [1] = "3";        Deck [0] [2] = "2";     Deck [0] [3] = "2";
    Deck [14] [0] = "Crimson Mage";             Deck [14] [1] = "2";        Deck [0] [2] = "2";     Deck [0] [3] = "2";
    Deck [15] [0] = "Elite Vanguard";           Deck [15] [1] = "1";        Deck [0] [2] = "2";     Deck [0] [3] = "1";
    Deck [16] [0] = "Embersmith";               Deck [16] [1] = "2";        Deck [0] [2] = "2";     Deck [0] [3] = "1";
    Deck [17] [0] = "Fallen Ferromancer";       Deck [17] [1] = "4";        Deck [0] [2] = "1";     Deck [0] [3] = "1";
    Deck [18] [0] = "Gideon's Lawkeeper";       Deck [18] [1] = "3";        Deck [0] [2] = "2";     Deck [0] [3] = "2";
    Deck [19] [0] = "Grand Abolisher";          Deck [19] [1] = "2";        Deck [0] [2] = "2";     Deck [0] [3] = "2";

    for (int i = 20; i < 40; i++)
    {
        Deck [i] [0] = "Mana";
        Deck [i] [1] = "Mana";
        Deck [i] [2] = "Mana";
        Deck [i] [3] = "Mana";
    }

}

void InitLife (short life [2])      //Sets the starting life for each player
{
    life [0] = 20;
    life [1] = 20;
}

int CoinFlip (short coinReturn)     //Flips the coin to determine which player starts
{
    srand (unsigned int(time (NULL)));
    short flipResult = rand() % 2;

    return flipResult;
}

/*void DumpArray (string array [40] [4])                    //dumps the names of everything in the deck, or it would if it was working
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        cout << array [i][0] << endl;
    }
}*/

void FirstHand (string Hand [7][4],string Deck [40][4])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        short deckCoutner = 40;

        srand (unsigned int(time (NULL)));
        short randCard = rand() % (deckCoutner);

        Hand [i] [0] = Deck [deckCoutner] [0];
        Hand [i] [1] = Deck [deckCoutner] [1];
        Hand [i] [2] = Deck [deckCoutner] [2];
        Hand [i] [3] = Deck [deckCoutner] [3];  

        deckCoutner-- ;
    }
}

int Draw ()
{

    return 0;
}

void main ()
{
    //int atoi (const char * str); 
    //This can be used to translate from string to int

    //Variables Start
    string Deck0 [40] [4];      //Player 0's Deck
    string Deck1 [40] [4];      //Player 1's Deck
    string Hand0 [7] [4];
    string Hand1 [7] [4];
    short life [2];             //Both PLayers life points. Player 0's life is in bin 0
    short turn = 0;             //who's turn is it? 0=P0, 1=P1, -1=Game is over
    //Variables End

    //**************************************************************************************GAME START**************************************************************************

    InitLife(life);
    short coinReturn = -1;                      //this is -1 just to deubg and see that it wasnt returning the number that it was initialized as
    coinReturn = CoinFlip (coinReturn);         //for some reason this always returns the same exact "random" number

    InitDeck (Deck0);                           //Initiallized Deck 0 for player 0
    InitDeck (Deck1);                           //Initiallized Deck 1 for player 1

    if (coinReturn == 0 )                       //decides who's turn it is based on the coinReturn result
    {
        turn = 0;
    }else
    {
        turn = 1;
    }

    //It has now been decided whos turn it is. I now need to make the two first hands for each player

    FirstHand (Hand0, Deck0);                   // Makes the first two hands out of the first two decks
    FirstHand (Hand1, Deck1);


    cout << coinReturn<<endl;

    system ("pause");
    return;
}
```

There is a dump array function in there that I just havent bothered to get functional so that's no worry of mine. This is for a school project so I am definatley not just asking for answers but I have been beating my head against a wall for the last  2 hours trying to figure this out. As I stated before,  I am positive that the answer to my question was within anther post that I have read, I just cannot seem to figure out where. Thank you so much for your help. I definitely feel like this is some gap in my knowledge of functions that I am missing.

I also fixed line 99 to this

```
void Upkeep (string board [10] [5]) //a function that does each players' upkeep
                                    //-1 is tapped, 0 is untapped. The 5th feild in the array is for tapped/untapped status
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
            board [i] [4] = "0";
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you fill the `Deck` array using a function? It'd be less error-prone and more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
short deckCoutner = 40;

    srand (unsigned int(time (NULL)));
    short randCard = rand() % (deckCoutner);

    Hand [i] [0] = Deck [deckCoutner] [0];
    Hand [i] [1] = Deck [deckCoutner] [1];
    Hand [i] [2] = Deck [deckCoutner] [2];
    Hand [i] [3] = Deck [deckCoutner] [3];
```

40 is too large of an index since you only initiate it with 40 elements.
40 would point to the 41st element

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was something stupid I was looking over! I cant tell you how much I appreciate it!

Comment: Alright so I am still having trouble finding the origin of this error. I understand that the 40 should have been 39. After switching that though I am still getting the same error. I am looking for any errors that are the same "out of scope" type thing but I cannot find anymore.

Comment: Did you just uncheck my answer as correct?  And here I was coming back to help you with an additional problem...

Comment: Im sorry, this is my first post. I was just clicking around not entirely sure of what I was doing. I apologize for doing so

Comment: No worries.   Alright so I can't find a second line with an out of bounds area.  Have you added any new code to your project?  And are you 100% sure you recompiled before running it again?  If those are not the issues you'll likely want to learn to use a debugger to find the exact line where the errors occurring.

Comment: Im using visual studio. The weird thing is, that even if I edit out the method that i just added, I still get the error. Ontop of that I would re-code the same method even ifI deleted it im sure

Comment: When you run in debug mode where do the debugger stop?  It should take you to a particular line

Answer (score 2):

`short deckCoutner = 40;` - the last element in your array is 39, not 40.

Also, only call `srand()` once at the beginning of your program.  If you keep calling it then you'll get the same random number back because the resolution of `time()` is low enough that it will return the same value each time, so you'll keep seeding the random number generator with the same value.